# Error of "Call a member function on non object" while var_dump get correct result

Tags: oop

I got error of "Call a member function embed() on a non-object", but I can see the result of var_dump is an object. Please help evaluate the following code:

This is the Class to create a picture:

```
Class Picture{
//....
function embed() {...}
//....
}
```

This is the Class for template:

```
Class Picture_Template{
$obj_id = $post->ID;
$pic = New Picture( $obj_id );
$this->obj = $pic;
}
```

This is a function to test the code:

```
function test_picture(){
global $pic_template;
$pic_template = new Picture_Template();
$obj =$pic_template->obj;
$obj_func =$obj->embed();
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $obj ); // I can see it is an object
var_dump( $obj_func ); // I can see the embed() function output correct result
}
```

This is the function that get the error message:

```
function play_button(){
echo get_play_button();
}

function get_play_button(){
global $pic_template;
if (!$obj )
 $obj =& $pic_template->obj;
if ( $obj->embed(){
//do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems `Picture_Template` is worthless - it's not even correctly formed (you need to place run-time code in a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)).

Plus you also seem to lack the basic understanding of [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) (like accessing `$post` and `$obj` within functions and classes, without globalising them first).

Here is what I think you're trying to do;

```
function test_picture()
{    
    $picture = new Picture( get_the_ID() );
    $picture_result = $picture->embed();

    /* debugging */
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $picture );
    var_dump( $picture_result );
    echo '</pre>';
}

function play_button()
{
    echo get_play_button();
}

function get_play_button()
{
    $picture = new Picture( get_the_ID() );

    if ( $embed = $picture->embed() ) {
        // do something & return something
    }

    return null; // return nothing if embed failed
}
```

Comment: there are lots of variables in the picture object, that's why I use a Picture Template Class-- can use $template->color, $template->width...,  Otherwise, I will need $picture= new Picture(get_the_ID) in each function to get each variable. But I will try your method first, to see how it works. Thanks!